# How can I properly use < and > operators for 2 vectors of integers when the first element of both are negative?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, operator-overloading

I'm writing a simple C++17 program that compares two vectors of integers.

e.g., I have two vectors: `a` represents the number -1, `b` 25

```
std::vector<int> a = {-1};
std::vector<int> b = {2, 5};
if(a < b)       std::cout << "a < b" << std::endl;
else if(a > b)  std::cout << "a > b" << std::endl;
else            std::cout << "a = b" << std::endl;
```

The output produced by the previous piece of code is `a < b`, and it is correct.
Let us consider now the following example:

```
std::vector<int> a = {-1, 9};
std::vector<int> b = {-1, 9, 9};
if(a < b)       std::cout << "a < b" << std::endl;
else if(a > b)  std::cout << "a > b" << std::endl;
else            std::cout << "a = b" << std::endl;
```

Here the output is `a < b` as well, but since -19 > -199 I would like it to be `a > b`.

There is a way to solve this? For example, I thought of converting the two vectors into integers and comparing them, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: using `<` with vectors will do a lexicographic comparison. Not a numeric comparison. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp 

And because "-19" is lexicographically less than "-199", well... you'll see the results you are getting.

Comment: Ok, the lexicographic comparison is not the desired action then. Is there another way to do what I want?

Comment: Yes. Do the comparison manually (transform vector into integer, then compare?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @MPops commented, using the overloaded operator `<` with `std::vector` will do a **lexicographical** comparison, which is not what you want (a numerical comparison).

Read more in the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp).

You need to do the numerical comparison of two vectors manually, by converting the `vector<int>` to an `int`, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T> int sgn(T val) {
    return (T(0) < val) - (val < T(0));
}

int vectorToInt(std::vector<int> v) {
  int result = 0;
  if(!v.size()) return result;
  result = result * 10 + v[0];
  for (size_t i = 1; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    result = result * 10 + (v[i] * sgn(v[0]));
  }
  return result;
}

int main(void) {
  std::vector<int> a_vec = {-1, 9};
  int a = vectorToInt(a_vec);
  std::vector<int> b_vec = {-1, 9, 9};
  int b = vectorToInt(b_vec);
  std::cout << "Comparing " << a << " with " << b << std::endl;

  if(a < b)       std::cout << "a < b" << std::endl;
  else if(a > b)  std::cout << "a > b" << std::endl;
  else            std::cout << "a = b" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Comparing -19 with -199
a > b
```

Comment: You are welcome @Tambuf, and also welcome to Stack Overflow! I included a full working example, have fun!